# Suggestion: Why not remember the previously entered tags and put these in by default?

Tags: feature-request, asking-questions, tags

It would be cool if the last used tags when asking a question are rememberd for the next question. To prevent errors, maybe not as default, but with a little button or link that says "insert previously used tags"? Sometimes there are a whole bunch of questions to the same topic, and it's tedious to type in those tags over and over again. I know someone who suffers from that a lot.

Comment: Ctrl + C, Ctrl + V seems like a better solution, rather than risking "generic default tags that you put on each question", in my opinion.

Comment: Or just type them, it's not *that* tedious.

Comment: Taking laziness into new extremes

Answer (score 3):

This is only a problem if someone asks lots of questions regularly (i.e. a small minority of SOFU users). And IMHO it is fairly easy to copy the tags from a previous question anyway.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that's required because of two reasons:

- How long is the longest tag name on SO?
- There already is an autocomplete facility for tags

Comment: Longest tag-name is 25 characters, which is the limit. Longest tag string would likewise be 125 characters, or 129 if you include the 4 delimitting spaces.

Comment: @ccomet Autocomplete should handle it, right? Btw, is there actually a 25 char long tag in use?

Comment: [accessviolationexception] is an example of a 24 character one off the top of my hat. I don't have any examples of legitimate 25 character tags as the majority of them (and there are a good number of them) are the result of truncating.

Comment: Well, for a legitimate non-truncated one, there's [object-relational-mapping].